# Python: How to store output of ls -lrt

Tags: python, ls

Problem : In python, how to store the o/p of 'ls -lrt' in a string so that we can search for files of a particular pattern

This is inorder to find all files in a directory that has been modified between date1 and date2

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the glob module to look for files with a pattern

Comment: Please do not ask the same question in slightly different manner only 20 minutes after you ask your first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> op = subprocess.check_output(["ls","-lrt"])
>>> print(op)
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+   4 henry  staff   136 16 Jun 11:20 Public
drwx------+   3 henry  staff   102 16 Jun 11:20 Movies
drwx------+   4 henry  staff   136 16 Jun 12:54 Pictures
drwx------@  48 henry  staff  1632 25 Jun 21:35 Library
drwx------+  39 henry  staff  1326 28 Jun 09:15 Desktop
drwx------+   8 henry  staff   272 28 Jun 12:24 Documents
drwx------+  19 henry  staff   646 29 Jun 15:15 Music
drwx------+ 146 henry  staff  4964 30 Jun 17:49 Downloads
```

Comment: But here, if we have to search for a pattern in the displayed o/p we are not able to as each character is treated separately and not as a line as a whole. 

Example :

import subprocess
op = subprocess.check_output(["ls","-lrt"])
for line in op:
    print line

Output: --> each alphabet is printed on each line and not a line as a whole

Comment: @Matt `op.split('\n')` will return the lines

Comment: I tried out and that dint work